# How to get all values for combobox from database except 1?

Tags: python, combobox, mysql-python, ttk

I have a Python program that end users insert their user name and password into the program and then the program inserts it into a MySQL database. The program can then pull the user names from a MySQL database and displays the data in a drop down `Combobox`. But there is one user name I would like to remain hidden from the end user. Here is my code:

```
try:
    connect()
    selectUsers = "select id, name from user"
    cursor.execute (selectUsers)

    bigfont = tkFont.Font(family = "Eurostile", size = 18)

    txtUsers = tk.StringVar()
    txtUsers.set("")
    drpUsers = ttk.Combobox(self, textvariable=txtUsers, state='readonly', font=("Eurostile", 18))#, bg = 'red', fg = 'white')
    root.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox.font", bigfont)
    for (id, name) in cursor:
        valueStatement.append(id)
    drpUsers['values'] = valueStatement
    drpUsers.grid(column = 4, row = 4)#, padx = 5)
    closeConnect()
except:
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Database Error", "ERR004 - There was an error communicating with the database")
```

Comment: Can't you just check for and skip it in the `for` loop? In other words, don't append the `id` for the `name` to `valueStatement`.

Comment: @martineau Thank you very much. That worked perfectly.

Comment: That's good to hear...problem solved!